# How to change the position of Bootstrap Navigation Bar parent menu item icon at mobile view?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am looking for a way to change the position of the *bootstrap navigation menu bar parent menu icon,* when open in mobile view.

Currently the menu header contains right-arrow-down icon at the end of header name like below.

[image]

My requirement is to convert the highlighted right-arrow-down icon to left-arrow icon and change the icon position to start of parent 
header menu text and also to change the background color (gray) of parent menu item on mouse hover like below.

[image]

below is the navigation menu bar HTML code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item" style="background-color: #f5f5f5; height:33px; padding-top:8px;">
        <label class="label d-md-block d-lg-none">Welcome, abc</label>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ACCOUNTS</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item"><span class="k-icon k-i-plus"></span>New Prospect</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item">Accounts</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item">Prospects</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item">Account Reports</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item">My Account Reports</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item"><span class="k-icon k-i-star"></span> Favorites</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">CONTACTS</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item"><span class="k-icon k-i-star"></span> Favorites</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">LEADS</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">         
            <a class="dropdown-item"><span class="k-icon k-i-star"></span> Favorites</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">OPPORTUNITIES</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ACTIVITIES</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

It might required to override the existing bootstrap classes to acheive this but I am not sure which class will work for me.
I have tried to look for the ways to acheive this using Bootstrap CSS online but not found any example similar to my requirement. Appreciate your help.

**Update:**
here is the mockup drop down of the modules from pressing the hamburger button in mobile view -

[image]

this would be the layout once one of the modules is selected (Opportunities is the module in this example) -

[image]

**Desktop View:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use font awesome icons like suggested below and create the similar effect you want. Bootstrap creates the triangle icon using border property on the after element of the toggable anchor. Remove that style by adding `border: 0 none;` and add the following styles to `.dropdown-toggle`

```
  .nav-item.dropdown {
    position: relative;
  }
  #navbarSupportedContent .dropdown-toggle::after,
  #navbarSupportedContent .dropdown-toggle::before {
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
  #navbarSupportedContent .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
    content: "\f105";
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
  }
  #navbarSupportedContent .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: "\f104";
  }
  #navbarSupportedContent .dropdown-toggle::after {
    border: 0 none;
  }
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .nav-item.dropdown {
    position: relative;
  }
  #navbarSupportedContent .dropdown-toggle::after,
  #navbarSupportedContent .dropdown-toggle::before {
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
  #navbarSupportedContent .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
    content: "\f105";
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
  }
  #navbarSupportedContent .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: "\f104";
  }
  #navbarSupportedContent .dropdown-toggle::after {
    border: 0 none;
  }
  .navbar-light #navbarSupportedContent .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/b71241fd62.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item" style="background-color: #f5f5f5; height:33px; padding-top:8px;">
        <label class="label d-md-block d-lg-none">Welcome, abc</label>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ACCOUNTS</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item"><span class="k-icon k-i-plus"></span>New Prospect</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">Accounts</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">Prospects</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">Account Reports</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">My Account Reports</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item"><span class="k-icon k-i-star"></span> Favorites</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">CONTACTS</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item"><span class="k-icon k-i-star"></span> Favorites</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">LEADS</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item"><span class="k-icon k-i-star"></span> Favorites</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">OPPORTUNITIES</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ACTIVITIES</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think i was not able to add proper requirements earlier. Please check I have added an update in the question. Mockup will help you to understand my requirement clearly. Thank you!

Comment: Please check my updated answer and let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you! Its working for mobile view now. But, the desktop view also change might be because you have added additional navigation bootstrap classes in your example which I copied. looking at same please see attached image for your reference.

Comment: Just add my styles in media query @media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {}, it should do the trick

Comment: working I did some changes in the class elements order. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i have example for you this is help for you

```
<nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-content">
      <div class="sidebar-menu">
        <ul>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">

              <p id="demo">Dashboard</p>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard 1
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard 3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar-menu  -->
    </div>

  </nav>
```

css

```
          @keyframes swing {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes sonar {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
body {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
.page-wrapper .sidebar-wrapper,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand > a,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-dropdown > a:after,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a:before,
.sidebar-wrapper ul li a i,
.page-wrapper .page-content,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search input.search-menu,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search .input-group-text,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a,
#show-sidebar,
#close-sidebar {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

/*----------------page-wrapper----------------*/

.page-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.page-wrapper .theme {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.page-wrapper .theme.chiller-theme {
  background: #1e2229;
}

/*----------------toggeled sidebar----------------*/

.page-wrapper.toggled .sidebar-wrapper {
  left: 0px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .page-wrapper.toggled .page-content {
    padding-left: 300px;
  }
}
/*--------------sidebar-wrapper----------------*/

.sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 260px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -300px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.sidebar-wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*----------------sidebar-content----------------*/

.sidebar-content {
  max-height: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar-content.desktop {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

/*--------------------sidebar-brand----------------------*/

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand #close-sidebar {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/*----------------------sidebar-menu-------------------------*/

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .header-menu span {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px 20px 5px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 30px 8px 20px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;

}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a:hover > i::before {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: swing ease-in-out 0.5s 1 alternate;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown > a:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f105";
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  background: 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 14px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu ul {
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li {
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a:before {
  content: "\f111";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 8px;

}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a span.label,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a span.badge {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a .badge,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a .label {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-submenu {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown.active > a:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: 10px;
}



/*-----------------------------chiller-theme-------------------------------------------------*/

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper {
    background: #31353D;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu {
    border-top: 1px solid #3a3f48;
    background-color : #171717;
}
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .active {
    border-top: 1px solid #3a3f48;
    background-color : #fff;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search input.search-menu,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search .input-group-text {
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-info .user-role,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-info .user-status,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search input.search-menu,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search .input-group-text,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand>a,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-footer>a {
    color: #818896;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li:hover>a,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown.active>a,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-info,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand>a:hover,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-footer>a:hover i {
    color: #b8bfce;
}

.page-wrapper.chiller-theme.toggled #close-sidebar {
    color: #bdbdbd;
}

.page-wrapper.chiller-theme.toggled #close-sidebar:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper ul li:hover a i,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a:hover:before,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search input.search-menu:focus+span,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown.active a i {
    color: #16c7ff;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(22, 199, 255, 0.5);
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a i,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown div,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search input.search-menu,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search .input-group-text {
    background: #3a3f48;

}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .header-menu span {
    color: #6c7b88;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-footer {
    background: #3a3f48;
    box-shadow: 0px -1px 5px #282c33;
    border-top: 1px solid #464a52;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-footer>a:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-footer>a:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

js

```
 var span = document.getElementById("deom"); 
        jQuery(function ($) {

    $(".sidebar-dropdown > a").click(function() {
  $(".sidebar-submenu").slideUp(200);
  if (
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .hasClass("active")
  ) {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .removeClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
    $(this)
      .next(".sidebar-submenu")
      .slideDown(200);


    $(this)
      .parent()
      .addClass("active");
  }
});

$("#close-sidebar").click(function() {
  $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
});
$("#show-sidebar").click(function() {
  $(".page-wrapper").addClass("toggled");
});




});
```

you can change color  using this css

```
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu {
    border-top: 1px solid #3a3f48;
    background-color : #171717;
}
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .active {
    border-top: 1px solid #3a3f48;
    background-color : #fff;
}
```

and you can edit arrow using this css

```
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown > a:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f105";
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  background: 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 14px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown.active > a:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: 10px;
}
```

you can change text using dom event in js

ex:-https://codepen.io/tharinduvindula/pen/zYxMQxo

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have to write that much of a code to do this single change. Few steps to follow

1) Remove the dropdown-toggle class as this is the commander behind the down arrow to appear.

2) Add fontawesome cdn or anything else for the arrow icons or you can use html unicode

3) Add appropriate fontawesome just inside the dropdown button or anything else, you can also use image icon.

4) For color change if you use fontawesome of anyother font base icon you can change the color or the icon too as like color:"anything" and to change the background color just target the button id or class and write background-color:"anythung"!important;

Example Code ::

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PDle/QlgIONtM1aqA2Qemk5gPOE7wFq8+Em+G/hmo5Iq0CCmYZLv3fVRDJ4MMwEA" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left mr-1"></i> Dropdown button
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-7aThvCh9TypR7fIc2HV4O/nFMVCBwyIUKL8XCtKE+8xgCgl/PQGuFsvShjr74PBp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this help! Thanks.